# Checking if a ruby hash contains a value greater than x

Tags: ruby, hash

I have the following object returned from an InfluxDB query, and I want to be able to check if any of the derivatives are equal or greater than say 100, if so then do stuff.

I've been trying to use select to check that field, but I really don't actually understand how to work with a data structure like this. How would I go about iterating through every derivative value in my returned object?

I'm not really seeing an example that's similar to my case in the enumerable documentation.
https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Enumerable.html

```
 [{
   "name" => "powerdns_value", 
             "tags" => nil,
             "values" => [
               { "time" => "2017-03-21T14:20:00Z", "derivative" => 1}, 
               { "time" => "2017-03-21T14:30:00Z", "derivative" => 900}, 
               { "time" => "2017-03-21T14:40:00Z", "derivative" => 0},  
               { "time" => "2017-03-21T15:20:00Z", "derivative" => 0}
             ]
}]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just want to know if one of the hashes in your array meet the condition

```
arr.first['values'].any? { |hash| hash['derivative'] >= 100 }
```